# Integral of a differential form along a non-defined path

Tags: differential-geometry, greens-theorem

Let $R>0$ and $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2<R^2,y>0\}$. Consider also $\omega (x,y)=x^2dx+2xydy$. My goal is to prove that $\int_{\partial_{+}\Omega}\omega=\frac{4}{3}R^3$, where $\partial _+ \Omega$ denotes the "edge" of $\Omega$ positively oriented. I know that using the Green-Riemann I can show that, but could I use the definition? That is:
$$\int_{\partial_{+}\Omega}\omega=\int_0^{\pi}(\omega \space\circ\space\gamma)(\theta)\gamma'(\theta)d\theta$$
Where $\gamma(\theta)=(R\cos(\theta),R\sin(\theta))$. On impulse I'd say it's not possible since it's not defined, but then again, the edge has $0$ volume, hence any semi circle suficiently together would be a pretty good approximation, thus it should work, what is your opinion?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the path is non-defined?!

Comment: Let $\Gamma_1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2=R^2}$ and $\Gamma_2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: y=0, -R\geq x \leq R\}$. I mean that $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \not\in \Omega$.

Comment: The boundary of the open region is still a perfectly defined curve. Some textbooks (professors) take the boundary of the closed region (where you include the boundary curve); either way, the curve is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do the computation that way. The boundary actually has two components:

- The straight component $C_1$, parameterised by $\gamma_1 : [-1, 1] \to C_1$ sending $t \mapsto (Rt, 0)$.
- The curved component $C_2$, parameterised by $\gamma_2 : [0, \pi] \to C_2$ sending $t \mapsto (R\cos t, R\sin t)$.

We can now evaluate the integral by pulling back the $1$-form $\omega$ to $[-1, 1]$ and $[0, \pi]$ via $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$.
\begin{align} \oint_{\partial_+ \Omega} \omega &= \int_{[-1, 1]} \gamma_1^\star (\omega)+\int_{[0,\pi]}\gamma_2^\star (\omega) \\ &= \int_{-1}^1 (Rt)^2(Rdt)  + \int_0^\pi \left( (R^2\cos^2 t).(-R\sin t\ dt) + (2R^2 \sin t \cos t).(R\cos t \ dt) \right) \\ &= \int_{-1}^1 R^3 t^2 dt + \int_{0}^{\pi} R^3 \sin t \cos^2 t \ dt \\ &= \frac{4}{3} R^3\end{align}

[To spell it out:
$$ \int_{[-1,1]} \gamma_1^\star (x^2 dx) = \int_{[-1, 1]} ((x \circ \gamma_1)(t))^2 \left( \frac{d(x \circ \gamma_1)}{dt}(t). dt \right) = \int_{-1}^1 (Rt)^2 \left( \frac{d(Rt)}{dt} dt\right)$$
and so on...]

A final remark: these integrals are not ill-defined at all. $\omega$ is a $1$-form, so you should expect to be able to integrate it along one-dimensional things like $\partial_+ \Omega$. The fact that $\partial_+ \Omega $ has zero measure as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ should not bother you.

Comment: I'm confortable with the fact that it has zero measure, what was confusing me is that the border of $\Omega$ was not explicitly defined, if it were $x^2+y^2\leq R^2$ then I would have no questions, but since math has such delicate details I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Bidon For the purposes of evaluating $\int_{\Omega} d \omega$, the fact that the boundary of $\Omega$ has zero measure _is_ relevant! That's because here, we're integrating a $2$-form on a $2$-dimensional space. So the two-dimensional measure becomes relevant.

Comment: … and therefore, $\int_{\Omega} d\omega = \int_{\bar \Omega} d\omega$ (where $\bar\Omega$ is the closure of $\Omega$ in $\mathbb R^2$, and $\omega$ has of course been extended smoothly to include the boundary).

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the boundary always have zero measure? Because in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is simply a line, hence no area, in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is a surface thus has no volume, and so forth into higher dimensions. What am I missing? PS: if at some point this starts to be annoying just ignore, if not, thank you so much for the patience

Comment: @Bidon True fact: $\int_{\bar \Omega} d\omega = \int_{\Omega} d\omega$ (because $\partial \Omega$ has zero measure when considered as a two-dimensional space). … BUT …. $\int_{\partial \Omega} \omega$ is non-zero (because $\partial \Omega$ has non-zero measure when considered as a one-dimensional space.

Comment: It's like how $[0,1]$ has measure $1$ when considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$, but $[0,1]\times \{ 0 \}$ has measure $0$ when considered as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. In the first case, I'm using the one-dimensional measure, but in the second example, I'm using the two-dimensional measure.

Comment: Yes, that I understand it's actually quite intuitive, but the conclusion I trying to get out of this is that it doesn't matter that the border of a space is explicitly defined or not in order to evaluate a 2-form differential, that is, the integral $\int_{\partial_{+}\Omega}\omega$ is the same wether $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2<R^2,y>0\}$ or $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x^2+y^2\leq R^2,y\geq 0\}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Bidon So I would do this computation in two steps. (1) First, I would argue that $\int_{\Omega} d\omega = \int_{\bar \Omega} d\omega$, using the fact that $\bar\Omega - \Omega$ has zero measure. (2) Next, notice that $\bar\Omega$ is a manifold-with-boundary! So $\int_{\bar\Omega} d\omega = \int_{\partial \bar\Omega} \omega$ by Stoke's theorem.

Comment: Ok, that definitely convinced me, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you